# APNs Message send to Server, No notification comes on device iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I have configured apns_certificate.pem and apns_privatekey.pem for server. I am using node.js server for sending push notification. I have successfully posted notification to apns server but device has not received any push notification.

I have also gone through [Troubleshooting Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG2) .
I have checked all pem files by following command on server side as it is described in the troubleshooting document.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert YourSSLCertAndPrivateKey.pem -debug -showcerts -CAfile server-ca-cert.pem
```

It was successful.

I checked that my server was able to connect to apns server by following commands.

```
$ telnet 1-courier.push.apple.com 5223
$ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
$ telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195
```

I configured it properly on iOS project and I am getting device token also.

But still I was not getting push notification on my device.

Comment: Was the application running when you sent the notification? If so: did you implement the corresponding methods?

Comment: The application was running on background. I have implemented "(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo" method also

Comment: Finally, I found that it was problem of server. The server was using Node.js. There are some problems with sending push notification to apns from node module. I use php server site code which is posted on RayWanderlich's push notification tutorial. it is working smooth.

Answer (score -2):

Please check device token is valid or not.
For which device token, server sending push notifications.
Also push notification should check on app background mode.

If all above correct you will receive push notification.

Also check this two methods in app delegate and send device token from your iOS app to server:

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken { 
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        NSLog(@"This is device token%@", str);
    }

    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err { 
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
        NSLog(@"Error %@",err);    
    }
```

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that I have got device token and registration was successful.

Comment: Then check server side code with device token for sending message to device.